# pseudo code for finding closed paths in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, pseudocode

I have an adjaceny matrix for a graph which tracks the edges between the nodes by having a 1 in the corresponding adjMat[i,j] = 1;
Through this adjaceny matrix i wish to find out all the closed paths of length 4 which exists in the graph. Can anyone please provide me with a pseudo code. thank u

Comment: How can it be C#, java and pseudocode?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like homework, so I won't give the whole thing away. But here's a hint: since you are interested in finding cycles of length 4, take the 4th power of the adjacency matrix and scan along the diagonal. If any entry M[i,i] is nonzero, there is a cycle containing vertex i.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is not the optimal way to compute it ( it's `O(n^4)` ), but a very straightforward way is scan through the all the vertices

```
a, b, c, d such that b > a, c > b, d > c
```

You can check then check for each of the following cycles:

```
 1. ([a,b] && [b,c] && [c,d] && [d,a])
 2. ([a,b] && [b,d] && [d,c] && [c,a]) 
 3. ([a,d] && [d,b] && [b,c] && [c,a])

 1:         2:        3:
 A---B      A---B     A   B
 |   |       \ /      |\ /|
 |   |        X       | X |
 |   |       / \      |/ \|
 D---C      D---C     C   D
```

You're basically checking every ordered set of vertices (a,b,c,d) for the 3 ways that they could form a cycle.

So the pseudo code would be:

```
for a = 0 to <lastVertex>
 for b = a + 1 to <lastVertex>
  for c = b + 1 to <lastVertex>
   for d = c + 1 to <lastVertex>

    if(IsCycle(a,b,c,d)) AddToList([a,b,c,d])
    if(IsCycle(a,b,d,c)) AddToList([a,b,d,c])
    if(IsCycle(a,c,b,d)) AddToList([a,c,b,d])

   next d
  next c
 next b    
next a
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a depth-limited depth-first-search to every node and record nodes where the DFS finds the starting node.
For the search, see pseudo-code here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-limited_search. You just need to add something like

```
if(node' == node && node'.depth==4) memorize(node)
```

to the beginning of the loop.